# Group flat associative array data by related identifier to form a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, grouping

I have this array:

```
array(
 "tour_0" => 1446,
 "tour_1" => 1471,
 "date-from-1471" => "2014-08-07",
 "date-to-1471" => "2014-08-15",
 "tour_2" => 30,
 "date-from-30" => 2014-08-01,
 "date-to-30" => 2014-08-05,
 "tour_3" => 10
)
```

Now, I need it to be grouped into this structure:

```
array(
 "0" => array("ID" => 1446),
 "1" => array("ID" => 1471, "from" => "2014-08-07", "to" => "2014-08-15"),
 "2" => array("ID" => 30, "from" => "2014-08-07", "to" => "2014-08-15"),
 "3" => array("ID" => 10),
)
```

How can I accomplish this thing?

Comment: Where does this array come from? It might be easier to restructure it at the source

Comment: It's coming out of a form (all the variables in $_POST, for saving a list), so there is no way to sort it "at the source".

Comment: Potentially modify your form then, because that's the source; instead of form fields with names like `tour_0`, use `tour[]`

Comment: *It's coming out of a form (all the variables in $_POST, for saving a list), so there is no way to sort it "at the source".* - **that's completely not true**. You can change the rendering of the form so that one set of form elements contains their names as array, e.g. instead of inputs with names `tour_0` and `tour_1` you will always render inputs with name `tour[0]` and `tour[1]` - and for all other fields respectively. Or even better if you call all fields like this: `tour[0][id]` + `tour[0][from]` + `tour[0][to]` - repeat this for each set of fields and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```php
$ret = [];
foreach($inputArray as $key => $value) {
  if (preg_match('/^tour_([0-9]+)/', $key)) {
    $ret[$value] = ["ID" => $value];
  }

  if (preg_match('/date-from-([0-9]+)/', $key, $matches)) {
    $ret[$matches[1]]["from"] = $value;
  }

  if (preg_match('/date-to-([0-9]+)/', $key, $matches)) {
    $ret[$matches[1]]["to"] = $value;
  } 
}

print_r($ret);
/*
Array
(
    "1446" => Array ("ID" => 1446),
    "1471" => Array ("ID" => 1471, "from" => "2014-08-07", "to" => "2014-08-15"),
    "30"   => Array ("ID" => 30, "from" => "2014-08-01", "to" => "2014-08-05"),
    "10"   => Array ("ID" => 10)
)*/
```

Close enough? (it is quite trival change the keys of the array, considering they are in order (0, 1, 2, 3, ...), if they are not, maybe you can save the order also (in another item of the subarray) and recompose again once this array is formed)

Comment: Glad to help, keep in mind, though, that what others are saying is true: if you have anyway to change the form, that would make your life esier (you could have *tour[0]*, *tour[1]*, *tour[2]*, ... with all the data populated directly from the request :-)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to write associative first level keys in the result array.  When an id row is encountered, immediately access its related "from" and "to" values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M1VGr))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (sscanf($k, 'tour_%d', $id)) {
        $result[$id]['ID'] = $v;
        foreach (['from', 'to'] as $prefix) {
            if (isset($array["date-$prefix-$v"])) {
                $result[$id][$prefix] = $array["date-$prefix-$v"];
            }
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Your sample data only contains tour keys that appear as prefixed indexes, so using those integers do not deviate from simply pushing values into an indexed result array.  You might decide to ignore those explicit keys and use `[]` to populate indexed entries.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/84Utt))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (str_starts_with($k, 'tour_')) {
        $row = ['ID' => $v];
        foreach (['from', 'to'] as $prefix) {
            if (isset($array["date-$prefix-$v"])) {
                $row[$prefix] = $array["date-$prefix-$v"];
            }
        }
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```